# how to do seeking in gstreamer pipeline (from filesrc to udpsink) before playing

Tags: c++, gstreamer, nvidia

I want to send a video file to multiple ports (with a same multicast ip address) using gstreamer pipeline. it works well (without seeking) when i run the pipeline in linux terminal.
but it should be seeked forward for a few seconds at the beginning time. By googling, I found out that the steps migth be like this:
1- Set the pipeline to PAUSED condition at the beginning.
2- perform query on the pipeline and seek the pipeline few seconds if seeking is enabled.
3- set the pipeline to PLAYING condition if seeking is done successfully.

```
//gst_player.cpp

#include <gst/gst.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>  
    
typedef enum {
    STATUS_DEFAULT,
    STATUS_PAUSED,
    STATUS_READY_TO_SEEK,
    STATUS_SEEKED,
    STATUS_READY_TO_PLAY,
    STATUS_PLAYING,
}MY_STATUS;    

typedef struct CfgStream_t {  
  std::string src;
  std::string ip_sink;
  std::string port_sink;
  GstElement *playbin;  
  MY_STATUS status;
  gboolean terminate;    
  gboolean seek_enabled; 
  gboolean seek_done;    
  gint64 duration;       
} CfgStream_t;    

static void handle_message (CfgStream_t *data, GstMessage *msg);    

/*
 * ./gst_player /home/mta/media.mp4 226.1.1.110 35000     
 *
*/

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  CfgStream_t data;
  GstBus *bus;
  GstMessage *msg;
  GstStateChangeReturn ret;
  GError* err = NULL;
  data.terminate = FALSE;
  data.seek_enabled = FALSE;
  data.seek_done = FALSE;
  data.duration = GST_CLOCK_TIME_NONE;
  data.status = STATUS_DEFAULT;

  if(argc >= 3) {
      /* Initialize GStreamer */
      gst_init (NULL, NULL);        
      try {
          data.src = std::string(argv[1]);
          data.ip_sink = std::string(argv[2]);
          data.port_sink = std::string(argv[3]);
      }
      catch(std::exception const &e) {
          g_printerr ("Unexpected source or sink information received.\n");
      }  
      
      std::string str_pipeline = "filesrc location=" + data.src + " ! qtdemux name=demux  demux.video_0 ! queue ! h264parse disable-passthrough=true !  decodebin ! omxh264enc insert-sps-pps=true bitrate=1000000 ! rtph264pay pt=96 ! udpsink host=" + data.ip_sink + " auto-multicast=true port=" + data.port_sink;    
      data.playbin = gst_parse_launch(str_pipeline.c_str(),&err);    
      if (!data.playbin) {
        g_printerr ("pipeline creation failed %s.\n",err->message);
        return -1;
      }          
      ret = gst_element_set_state (data.playbin, GST_STATE_PAUSED);
      if (ret == GST_STATE_CHANGE_FAILURE) {
        g_printerr ("Unable to set the pipeline to the playing state.\n");
        gst_object_unref (data.playbin);
        return -1;
      }

      /* Listen to the bus */
      bus = gst_element_get_bus (data.playbin);
      do {
        msg = gst_bus_timed_pop_filtered (bus, 100 * GST_MSECOND, GstMessageType(GST_MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGED | GST_MESSAGE_ERROR | GST_MESSAGE_EOS | GST_MESSAGE_DURATION | GST_MESSAGE_ASYNC_DONE));

        /* Parse message */
        if (msg != NULL) {
          handle_message (&data, msg);
        } else {              
          if(data.status == STATUS_READY_TO_SEEK && !data.seek_done) {
              g_print ("\n ENTER to Seeking mode...\n");
              if (!gst_element_seek (data.playbin, 1.0, GST_FORMAT_TIME, GstSeekFlags(GST_SEEK_FLAG_FLUSH | GST_SEEK_FLAG_KEY_UNIT),
                                       GST_SEEK_TYPE_SET, 10 * GST_SECOND,
                                       GST_SEEK_TYPE_NONE, GST_CLOCK_TIME_NONE)) {
                  g_print("Seek failed!\n");
              }
              data.seek_done = TRUE;
          }   
          
          if(data.status == STATUS_READY_TO_PLAY) {    
              ret = gst_element_set_state (data.playbin, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
              if (ret == GST_STATE_CHANGE_FAILURE) {
                g_printerr ("Unable to set the pipeline to the playing state.\n");
                gst_object_unref (bus);
                gst_element_set_state (data.playbin, GST_STATE_NULL);
                gst_object_unref (data.playbin);
                return -1;
              }
              g_print ("\n ENTER to PLAYING mode... %d ...\n", ret); // GST_STATE_CHANGE_ASYNC is returned
          }    
        }
      } while (!data.terminate);

      /* Free resources */
      gst_object_unref (bus);
      gst_element_set_state (data.playbin, GST_STATE_NULL);
      gst_object_unref (data.playbin);

  }
  else {
      g_printerr ("Number of Input arguments should be 3.\n");
  }

  return 0;
}

static void handle_message (CfgStream_t *data, GstMessage *msg) {
  GError *err;
  gchar *debug_info;

  switch (GST_MESSAGE_TYPE (msg)) {
    case GST_MESSAGE_ERROR:
      gst_message_parse_error (msg, &err, &debug_info);
      g_printerr ("Error received from element %s: %s\n", GST_OBJECT_NAME (msg->src), err->message);
      g_printerr ("Debugging information: %s\n", debug_info ? debug_info : "none");
      g_clear_error (&err);
      g_free (debug_info);
      data->terminate = TRUE;
      break;
    case GST_MESSAGE_EOS:
      g_print ("\nEnd-Of-Stream reached.\n");
      data->terminate = TRUE;
      break;
    case GST_MESSAGE_DURATION:
      /* The duration has changed, mark the current one as invalid */
      data->duration = GST_CLOCK_TIME_NONE;
      break;
    case GST_MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGED: {
      GstState old_state, new_state, pending_state;
      gst_message_parse_state_changed (msg, &old_state, &new_state, &pending_state);
      if (GST_MESSAGE_SRC (msg) == GST_OBJECT (data->playbin)) {
        g_print ("Pipeline state changed from %s to %s:\n",
            gst_element_state_get_name (old_state), gst_element_state_get_name (new_state));
        if(new_state == GST_STATE_PAUSED) {
            if(data->status == STATUS_DEFAULT) {
               GstQuery *query;
               gint64 start, end;
               query = gst_query_new_seeking (GST_FORMAT_TIME);
               if (gst_element_query (data->playbin, query)) {
                 gst_query_parse_seeking (query, NULL, &data->seek_enabled, &start, &end);
                 if (data->seek_enabled) {
                   g_print ("Seeking is ENABLED from %" GST_TIME_FORMAT " to %" GST_TIME_FORMAT "\n",
                       GST_TIME_ARGS (start), GST_TIME_ARGS (end));
                   data->status = STATUS_READY_TO_SEEK;
                 } else {
                   g_print ("Seeking is DISABLED for this stream.\n");
                 }
               }
               else {
                 g_printerr ("Seeking query failed.");
               }
               gst_query_unref (query);
            }
            if(data->status == STATUS_READY_TO_SEEK && data->seek_done) {
                g_print ("SEEK Complete and I am ready to Play.\n");
                data->status = STATUS_READY_TO_PLAY;
            }
        }        
        else if(new_state == GST_STATE_PLAYING){
            data->status = STATUS_PLAYING;
        }        

      }
    } break;
  case GST_MESSAGE_ASYNC_DONE:
      g_print ("\nI am in ASYNC mode. \n");
      
      break;
    default:
      /* We should not reach here */
      g_printerr ("Unexpected message received.\n");
      break;
  }
  gst_message_unref (msg);
}
```

I have traced steps using printed messages in terminal. first and second steps are done successfully.
but when I set pipeline to playing condition,  It returns GST_STATE_CHANGE_ASYNC and playing is not performed.

Comment: What is the output of your `gst-discoverer-1.0 /home/mta/media.mp4` file?

Comment: @Daniel Chaves Topology:  container: Quicktime    video: H.264 (Constrained Baseline Profile)
Properties:  Duration: 0:00:30.900000000  Seekable: yes  Live: no  Tags:       video codec: H.264 / AVC      bitrate: 613966      encoder: Lavf58.20.100      container format: ISO MP4/M4A

Comment: @Daniel Chaves  Do you mean that the problem is caused by Nvidia converters? My code is running on Nvidia Jetson nano

Comment: Can I see your pipeline?

Comment: It's working on my x86 and its encoders. Couple of tips, 1) add the caps after omxh264enc like `video/x-h264, stream-format=byte-stream`, 2) Create a new H264 video with: `gst-launch-1.0 -v videotestsrc ! videoconvert ! omxh264enc ! qtmux ! filesink location=output.mp4` and use that one. 3) Add `config-interval=-1` property to `h264parse` element.  4) Is the pipeline working if you try with gst-launch-1.0?

Comment: Sender: `gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=video.mp4 ! qtdemux  ! queue ! h264parse config-interval=-1 disable-passthrough=true !  decodebin ! x264enc bitrate=1000000 ! video/x-h264,stream-format=byte-stream ! rtph264pay pt=96 ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000`. Receiver: `gst-launch-1.0 -v udpsrc port=5000 caps="application/x-rtp" ! queue ! rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 ! queue ! videoconvert ! autovideosink`. This sender with the app works fine as well.

Comment: Yes. The pipeline is working with gst-launch-1.0. but I need to use seeking.

Comment: @DanielChaves you are right and the app is working on x86 when x264enc is used instead of omxh264enc. but i want to use this pipeline on jetson nano. but the following error appears even gst-launch-1.0 is used (in jetson nano): from qtdemux0: internal data stream error.

Comment: there are 2 points. 1- the first pipeline (with omxh264enc) is working with gst-launch-1.0 (without seeking) but it doesnt work with equivalent app (after seeking) on jetson nano. 2- the second pipeline (with x264enc) works well on x86 and app makes seeking with no problem. but x264enc element seems to have problems with nvidia

Comment: If you try another encoder like NVIDIA one nvv4l2h264enc, will it work? Just update the `str_pipeline` to: `std::string str_pipeline = "filesrc location=" + data.src + " ! qtdemux name=demux  demux.video_0 ! queue ! h264parse disable-passthrough=true ! decodebin ! nvvidconv ! \"video/x-raw(memory:NVMM),format=I420\" !  nvv4l2h264enc ! video/x-h264,stream-format=byte-stream ! rtph264pay pt=96 ! udpsink host=" + data.ip_sink + " auto-multicast=true port=" + data.port_sink;`.

Comment: it makes the message of "Seeking is Disabled for this stream" (in handle_message(...) function) then it goes to GST_MESSAGE_ASYNC_DONE.